# Determinants of block tridiagonal matrices when off-diagonal blocks are not m*m matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant, block-matrices

We know that if we have the block-tridiagonal matrix $M(z)$ with blocks $A_i$, $B_i$ and $C_{i−1}$ (i =1,...,n) which are all $m \times m$ matrices 
$$M(z)=\begin{bmatrix}
A_1 & B_1 & \cdots &\frac{1}{z}C_0\\
C_1 & \ddots & \ddots&  \\
\vdots & \ddots & \ddots& B_{n-1}\\
zB_n & & C_{n-1}& A_n
\end{bmatrix}$$
where the off-diagonal blocks are nonsingular, it can be associated with a transfer matrix, 
$$T=\begin{bmatrix}
-B_n^{-1}A_n& -B_n^{-1}C_{n-1} \\
I_m & 0 
\end{bmatrix} 
\cdots \begin{bmatrix}
-B_1^{-1}A_1& -B_1^{-1}C_0 \\
I_m & 0 
\end{bmatrix} 
$$
where $ I_m$ is the $ m×m$ unit matrix and 
$$\det(T)=\prod_{i=1}^\infty \det[B_i^{-1}C_{i-1}]  $$

But what will the transfer matrix $T$ and the determinant $\det(T)$ be if $B_i$ and $C_{i}$ are $m \times n$ matrices ($m$ is not equal to $n$) instead of $m\times m$ matrices?  What's the new formula for that?

Thank you!!